# Подстроки в с++

Tags: c++, строки

Помогите пожалуйста.

> Написать функцию,которая возвращает индекс первого символа подстроки
>   если данная подстрока содержится в строке.

Вот все, что смог написать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
void f1(char ch,char a[],char b[]) {         
}

int main() {
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
     char a[256],b[256];
     int k,j;
     cout << "Введите главную строку: ";
     cin >> a;
     cout << "Введите подстроку для главной строки: ";
     cin >> b;
     for(k = 0; k < b[] != '\0'; k++) {
         for(k = 0; k < a[] != '\0'; k++) {
             if(a[k] == b[k]) {
                 cout << b[1] << endl;
             }
         }
     }
     return 0;
     system("pause");
}
```

Выдает ошибки:

> main.cpp:17:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token

и

> main.cpp:19:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token

Comment: `k<b[]!='\0'` - это что такое?

Comment: подсчет символов в строке,пока не встретиться нулевой знак

Comment: А почему в скобках ничего нет? Там должен быть номер символа, к которому вы хотите обратиться.

Comment: этим проблемы не решатся

Comment: вопрос не понятен, потому что если   найдена подстрока, т.е. strstr(a, b) != nullptr, то  результатом всегда  будет  нуль

Comment: Даю подсказку: задача найти позицию **j** в большой строке, такая, что `a[j+i] == b[i]`, где **i** это индекс всех букв второй строки. `∃j∈a : ∀i∈b a[j+i]==b[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать std::string и его методы:

```
size_t foo(const std::string& str, const std::string& sub_str) {
    return str.find(sub_str);
}
```

В случае, если подстрока не найдена, вернется std::string::npos

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    string a, b;
    cout << "Введите главную строку: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Введите подстроку для главной строки: ";
    cin >> b;

    if((int)a.find(b) != -1)
        cout << a.find(b);
    else
        cout << "Ответа нет";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу на Ваш вопрос следующим кодом (код будет реализован в moder C++)

Краткое описание - воспользуйтесь алгоритмом search в связке с boyer_moore_horspool_searcher (для скоростного поиска подстроки)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>


#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)


long int PosOfEntry(std::string main_string, std::string sub_string) {
    auto iteratorOFEntry = std::search(std::begin(main_string),
                                       std::end(main_string),
                                       std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher(std::begin(sub_string), std::end(sub_string)));
    if (iteratorOFEntry == std::end(main_string)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return std::distance(std::begin(main_string), iteratorOFEntry);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    std::string main_string{"Main string test"};
    std::string sub_string{"string"};

    std::cout << "[Out] Position : " << PosOfEntry(main_string, sub_string) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```